# Enable drawing features by keeping pressing ctrl in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to add a function that enabling drawing function when keeping pressing 'ctrl', e.g., a circle.

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false})
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle'
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        draw.setActive(true);
        map.addInteraction(draw)
    }
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        draw.setActive(false);
        map.removeInteraction(draw)
    }
})
```

This does not work when I press ctrl, but works fine if I modify the code to detect shift keypress to enable draw function.

I think I must miss something. Could you tell me why pressing ctrl doesn't work but shift works fine? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It's not EXACTLY what you want but its really near what you need.

How i bypass your problem:

If you want to hold control key for drawing it doesn't work for me too. The interaction seems to work but in fact no drawing happens.

**But** if you use CTRL key as a toogle. I mean if you press one time for starting drawing, draw your shapes and then press again CTRL key to stop it, then i can do it for you.

You can do it with the following codes:

Here is the **map code**:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([0, 20], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom: 3
            })
});
```

Here is the **features layer/collection** where we stored the drawing features

```
var drawingFeatures = new ol.Collection();
// The layer of these drawing features
var drawingLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector({features: drawingFeatures}),
     style: new ol.style.Style({
         fill: new ol.style.Fill({
             color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
         }),
         stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: '#ffcc33',
              width: 2
         }),
         image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: 7,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                   color: '#ffcc33'
              })
         })
     })
});
drawingLayer.setMap(map);               // put the layer in our map
```

Here is the **drawing interaction**:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false}),
    type: 'Circle',                     // type of draw
    features: drawingFeatures           // features where to store drawings
});
```

And finally the **listener wich start/stop the draw interaction**:

```
var drawingFlag = false;                // flag for start drawing
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // the key code of the key we must hit to draw features
    // CTRL = 17
    // Note that SHIFT key is already used for zooming area by default
    var keyCode = 17; 

    if (e.keyCode === keyCode) {        // if its the good keycode

        if(drawingFlag === false) {
            //console.info("Start drawing");
            draw.setActive(true);       // activate draw
            map.addInteraction(draw);   // add interaction draw
            drawingFlag = true;         // start drawing flag
        }
        else {
            //console.info("Stop drawing");
            draw.setActive(false);      // deactivate draw
            map.removeInteraction(draw);// remove interaction draw
            drawingFlag = false;        // stop drawing flag
        }
    }
});
```

It works great for me with this!